# Push to Heroku from Jenkins

Tags: django, git, heroku, jenkins

## Can't push django app from Jenkins Machine

I am pushing my code to heroku via git. I am receiving an error pushing the same repo to the same remote when I do it on my jenkins box and am receiving no error when pushing locally.

### From local

```
~/code/github/jenkinshub: git remote -v
  heroku    git@heroku.com:vast-oasis-9739.git (fetch)
  ...

~/code/github/jenkinshub: git push heroku master
  Counting objects: 69, done.
  ...    
  -----> Python app detected

~/code/github/jenkinshub: git log
  commit 09de133d179f5be6d699c750a26a7ebf3f05a894
```

### From jenkins box

```
~ git remote -v
  heroku    git@heroku.com:vast-oasis-9739.git (fetch)
  ...

~ git push heroku master
  Counting objects: 65, done.
  ...
  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

~ git log
  commit 09de133d179f5be6d699c750a26a7ebf3f05a894
```

Comment: One difference I can see is that in the jenkins repo, the clone occurred into a 'workspace' directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory that jenkins clones the repo into is named "workspace". For some reason, this name mismatch caused a refection from the pre-commit hook of heroku. I pushed from the jenkins box to the remote repo from a different directory named "jenkinshub" and it worked. I created a simple post build script to handle the push.

### Post Build Script

```
$ cd ..
$ sudo rm -rf jenkinshub
$ sudo cp -R workspace jenkinshub
$ sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat jenkinshub
$ cd jenkinshub
$ sudo su tomcat
$ git push heroku master
```